# In a to do list, keep record in a database when a checkbox was checked through a jquery + ajax script

Tags: jquery, ajax

I would like to record in my database the tasks done in a to do list. For that, I need to send the checked/unchecked through a jquery + aajx send to my BDD. Can you, please, help me to correct this script? Cheers.

```
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input:checkbox').click(function() {
$('input:checkbox').is(':checked');
 $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: 'send.php',
            data: 'id='+$(this).attr(("input:checkbox").checked()"),
            success: function(){ },
            error: function(){ alert('failed');}
    }); 
});
});
</script>

<html><body>
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="taskdone_1" >
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="taskdone_2" >
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1):

**1st:** `.change` instead of `.click`

**2nd:** pass data like `data : { id : Id_Here}`

**3rd:** to get id use `.attr('id')`

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">  
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $('input:checkbox').on('change',function() {
        var ThisIt = $(this),
        Data = { id : ThisIt.attr('id') };
        if(this.checked){
          $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: 'send.php',
            data: Data,
            success: function(response){ console.log(response); },
            error: function(){ alert('failed');}
          });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Then you can catch the data in php with

```
echo $_POST['id']; // after that the response in the ajax success should return the input id
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some points you must understand on your code:

**First**, this line: `$('input:checkbox').is(':checked');` doesn't have any sense like this. It returns `boolean`, so you must use it into condition.

```
if ($('input:checkbox').is(':checked')) {
    // action here
}
```

**Then**, you have to use `change` event to instead of `click` event.

**Last**, pass data as `Object` instead of passing it directly . The line which contains `'id='+$(this).attr(("input:checkbox").checked()")` too doesn't make any sense.

Here will be your code

```
$('input:checkbox').on('change',function() {
    if(this.checked){ // short hand of $(this).is(':checked')
      $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: 'send.php',
        data: { id : $(this).attr('id') },
        dataType: 'json'
        success: function(response){ console.log(response); },
        error: function(){ alert('failed');}
     });
   }
});
```

Thanks for your answer. It works, but I have to add a condition of an unchecked task in my to do list. So, the full code is :

```
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
 </script>
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('input:checkbox').on('change',function() {
    var ThisIt = $(this),
    Data = { id : ThisIt.attr('id') };

    if(this.checked){   
      $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: 'send1.php',
        data: Data,
        success: function(response){ console.log(response); },
        error: function(){ alert('failed');}
      });
    }
    else {  
      $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: 'send2.php',
        data: Data,
        success: function(response){ console.log(response); },
        error: function(){ alert('failed');}
      });
    }   

    });
});
</script>
```